# XtraDB or InnoDb. Which to choose on a website with high concurrency of reads and writes

Tags: mysql, innodb

We have MySQL 4 master masters and several read slaves of each master running MySQL. We roll with InnoDB, should we be looking towards XtraDB?

We have to be able to average many comments a second which typically trigger 10 inserts and 100 reads.

Answer (score 3):

Either will work.

There are both performance an usability enhancements in XtraDB you will be able to benefit from:  http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtradb:features:start

It's best not to think of XtraDB as more of a series of after market enhancements than a complete fork - as it still re-bases itself against newer MySQL releases.